# Installing an Android widget along with it's associated app

Tags: android, deployment, widget

Developed an app that is feature intensive. (Complete and in testing)

User requests a widget on the home screen to display some summary data that will receive updates from the database that the app works with.

The widget is not difficult to create.

My question revolves around deployment.  I want to be able to launch the app from the widget.

This of course means I have to install the app on the device along with the widget.

What is the deployment protocol for something like this or am I going about this the wrong way?

Summary:

1. Developed app
2. Developed widget that displays summary info entered through the app
3. Tapping on widget will launch app
4. How to deploy both together

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just package the Widget in the app? Gmail has a widget. Messaging has a widget. There's really no compelling reason to have two separate apks for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So I think is illustrates my ignorance on the topic.

Ideally I definitely do NOT want to have two separate apks.  

I think I understand what you mean but I'm curious how does one go about packaging the Widget in the app so that they both install?

I was under the impression that they are two separate entities

Do I just add them as receivers in the manifest of my app?